# How to overlap two sounds in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio-processing

I am trying to build a sound annotator in Matlab.

One of the requirements for this annotator is to be able to take a recording sample(or prerecorded file) and then add it on top of the existing file.

Let's say i have the first file:

```
[y,Fs] = audioread(filename);
```

and the second file

```
[x,Fs2] = audioread(filename2);
```

The first file can be a music clip, the second file is just some recorded commentary. Is there a way to create a new sound file using the first file as a base and then adding the second file on top of it at a certain time( let's say at minute 2, second 3) so that you can hear both the music and the recorded speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your signals have the same sampling frequency

```
x2 = resample(x, Fs, Fs2);
```

After that you can simply add the two signals together.

```
offset = (2 * 60 + 3) * Fs;
output = y;
output(offset:offset+length(x2);:) = output(offset:offset+length(x2);:) + x2
```

Probably you want to apply a gain to control the volume of the two recordings and also the overall volume.

```
output = music_volume * y;
output(offset:offset+length(x2);:) = (output(offset:offset+length(x2);:) + commentary_volume * x2);
output = volume * output;
```